Difference of Lorentz Correlator and Euclidean Correlator
In Effective Field Theory lecture notes by David Simmons-Duffin, he puts efforts on trying to show the similar exponentially-decaying behavior of Euclidean correlator in Lorentz correlator.
Consider $\hat{\mathcal{O}}(t)$ to be local operator and $|\psi\rangle$ to be eigenstates of Hamiltonian, we have the Euclidean correlator and Lorentz correlator to be
$$
\begin{align}
\tag1\langle\Omega|\hat{\mathcal{O}_{\text{E}}}(\tau = it)\hat{\mathcal{O}_{\text{E}}}(0)|\Omega\rangle &= \sum_{\psi}|\langle\psi|\hat{\mathcal{O}}_{\text{E}}(0)|\Omega\rangle|^2e^{-E_{\psi}t}\\
\tag2\langle\Omega|\hat{\mathcal{O}}(t)\hat{\mathcal{O}}(0)|\Omega\rangle &= \sum_{\psi}|\langle\psi|\hat{\mathcal{O}}(0)|\Omega\rangle|^2e^{-iE_{\psi}t}
\end  {align}
$$
Simmons-Duffin explains that actually the Lorentz correlators can be seen as distribution, and we can see their behavior by integration with smooth function, which recovers the exponential-decaying like Euclidean correlator.
Although he provides reason that in order to make Lorentz correlators convergent, we must view them as distribution, I'm still confused about why we have to, to me, the only difference between Euclidean correlators and Lorentz ones is Wick rotation, is there any connection between Wick rotation and distribution?
